# How to use UWP Platform::StringReference

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

It appears that my code is doing a lot of `new/delete` in the following method to convert C string to `Platform::String` (doing it once per half a second and the text is about 100-200KB that is accumulated by a third-party C code)

```
String^ ToPlatformString(const char* str)
{
    if (str == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    auto length = strlen(str);
    wchar_t * wcstr = new wchar_t[length + 1];
    size_t num_converted = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&num_converted, wcstr, length + 1, str, _TRUNCATE);

    auto res = ref new String(wstr);
    delete[] wstr;
    return res;
}
```

I know that internally, `Platform::String` constructor basically makes a new copy of the passed string `wstr`. Is there a way to eliminate this redundancy? Note that I also want the `Platform::String` instance to free the allocated data if it is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your title suggests, your best bet is the StringReference built-in type. There is good documentation of that class here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/strings-c-cx#stringreference

Your success using this approach will depend quite a bit on your usage pattern, primarily due to two limitations on StringReference:

1. Not reference counted - regular C++ object, intended for stack allocation.
2. Only one assignment/conversion to String^ permitted without performance hit - second assignment will trigger a copy.

So you could get away with something like this:

```
void UseAsPlatformString(wchar_t *wcstr)
{
    Platform::StringReference ref(wcstr);
    AFunction(ref.GetString());     // GetString() not required, shown for clarity.
}

void AFunction(Platform::String ^arg)
{
   // Do something with arg.
   // Don't do this:
   //   Platform::String ^ref2 = arg;
}
```

What function you want to call needs to act directly on the passed-in string, ad not make other references to the string which would push the reference count above 1. My understanding is that if the count goes above 1, then a copy will be made.

Comment: My only reason for conversion is to push the result to the UI. The third-party C library is run in an off-UI thread i.e. in a `create_task`. The `Platform::String` (converted from `const char*`) is to be used as a data binding property. Also, do you happen to know the destruction behavior?

Comment: I doubt that StringReference would work for data binding purposes - I think you'll wind up with a reference count above 1 in those situations.

As for destruction - the StringReference only "borrows" the underlying string, and relies on the underlying C string continuing to live on longer than  the lifetime of the StringReference. I wouldn't pass a StringReference across threads - the lifetime's too hard to manage. You could pass the C string across threads (with an implied transfer of ownership) and then build a StringReference on the UI thread.

Comment: I guessed the designer of the API never thought about this use case; which I think is the main reason we use `Platform::String`.

Comment: WinRT is a binary contract that is language-neutral; it can't make assumptions about how C or C++ manages memory (or any other language, for that matter). Hence objects like strings are reference-counted.